# resizeTo doesn't resize window issue (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below. I am refreshing the page with a non maximized window. The width reported in the 3 cases are the same. Why isn't resizeTo increasing the window's width by 100?

Also the width reported by jQuery and the width from Javascript are different in Firefox and IE10. In Chrome they are the same. Why these descrepenices in values and between browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
      $(document).ready(function ($) {
        if (window.console) console.log("Old width: " + $(window).width());
        window.setTimeout(WindowResize, 3000);

        //WindowResize();

      });

      function WindowResize()
      {
        if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1)
          {
            width = document.body.offsetWidth;
            height = document.body.offsetHeight;
          }
        else
          {
            width = window.outerWidth;
            height = window.outerHeight;
          }

        if (window.console) console.log("Old width2: " + $(window).width() +  "   width: " + width);
        window.resizeTo(width + 100, height);
        if (window.console) console.log("New width: " + $(window).width());
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers do not support this unless the `window` you are trying to resize is a popup.